# Discord.py - How to make a simple calculator?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'd like to add a simple calculator to my bot but I can't use the command.

Here's my code:

```py
@bot.command
async def calc(ctx):
    def check(m):
        return len(m.content) >= 1 and m.author != client.user

    await ctx.send("Number 1: ")
    number_1 = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await ctx.send("Operator: ")
    operator = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await ctx.send("Number 2: ")
    number_2 = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    try:
        number_1 = float(number_1.content)
        operator = operator.content
        number_2 = float(number_2.content)
    except:
        await ctx.send("Invalid input")
        return
    if operator == "+":
        output = number_1 + number_2
    elif operator == "-":
        output = number_1 - number_2
    elif operator == "/":
        output = number_1 / number_2
    elif operator == "*":
        output = number_1 * number_2
    else:
        await ctx.send("invalid input")
        return
    await ctx.send("Answer: " + str(output))
```

As I can see, there're no errors, but the bot ignores me inputting the command. I tried to use `_calc` (as my bot's prefix is `_`) but nothing works. I'd be grateful for your help!

Comment: `@bot.command()` you need the `()`

Comment: @TakuThe Unfortunately, even with `()` my code doesn't work

Comment: @GhostOps You mean overall in the entire bot code? Or pointwisely in this command?

Comment: yes in the entire bot code

Comment: @GhostOps Yes, I do

Answer (score 2):

As you are having `on_message` in your bot code, all your bot prefix commands will get end up processed in the `on_message` function, overriding every other `bot.command` functions

So, To fix this, add a `bot.process_commands(message)` line at the end of your `on_message`. For example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do some extra stuff here
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

But you can better place your `on_message` inside a listener. This also allows you to do multiple things asynchronously in response to a message.
For example:

```py
@bot.listen('on_message')
async def whatever_you_want_to_call_it(message):
    # do stuff here
    # do not process commands here
```

For more reference, [Why does on-message make my commands stop working?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: I'd like to ensure: Should it look like [this](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/dd/05/61/dd056176e067bd78bca205c40f873c5f.jpg)? (This is screenshot of the code)

Comment: @Aaron no, pls dont change the function name to on_message, thats wrong...

Comment: @Aaron do u have a separate function called `on_message` in your code under `bot.event` decorator? if yes, change its format into the above mentioned way so that your prefix commands would work

Comment: I'm not really strong in coding as for now, so could you please explain what does `function called on_message in my code under bot.event decorator`?

Comment: @Aaron in your screenshot, you changed the function name from calc to on_message and bot.command to bot.event, just undo the changes, and change the on_message function under bot.event function as like mentioned at my answer, thats what i was saying